# Chat server client sometimes cannot see message from other clients on the same server

Tags: java, class, server, client, project

I am making 2 classes for Chat server client for a project I am working on. The problem is server can see the message that sent to it(from client) and it can send those messages out to every clients **BUT** each client has to type in some input first if he wants to see the message from other users. I have no clue what I did wrong. Please help me out. Thanks in advance :)

Server Class

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*; 

public class TestServer extends Thread
{ 
protected Socket clientSocket;
public static ArrayList<Socket> ConnectionArray = new ArrayList<Socket>();
public static ArrayList<String> CurrentUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
final static int PORT = 22;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{ 
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 

    try
    {           
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT); 
        System.out.println ("Connection Socket Created");
        try 
        { 
            while (true)
            {
                 System.out.println ("Waiting for Connection");
                 Socket sock = serverSocket.accept();
                 ConnectionArray.add(sock);
                 System.out.println("Client connected from: " + sock.getLocalAddress().getHostName());                   
                 new TestServer (sock);                   
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            System.err.println("Accept failed."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
         System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + PORT); 
         System.exit(1); 
    } 
    finally
    {
         try {
              serverSocket.close(); 
             }
         catch (IOException e)
             { 
              System.err.println("Could not close port: 10008."); 
              System.exit(1); 
             } 
        }
   }

    private TestServer (Socket inSock)
  {
    clientSocket = inSock;
    start();
  }

public void run()
{
    System.out.println ("New Communication Thread Started");
    //System.out.println ("Client connected from: " + sock.getLocalAddress().getHostName());

    try { 
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true); 
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( clientSocket.getInputStream())); 

         String inputLine; 

         while (true) 
             { 
                inputLine = in.readLine();
                System.out.println ("Server: " + inputLine);   

                  for(int i = 1; i <= TestServer.ConnectionArray.size(); i++)
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Total Connection: " + ConnectionArray.size());
                        Socket TEMP_SOCK = (Socket) TestServer.ConnectionArray.get(i-1);
                        if (clientSocket != TEMP_SOCK)
                       {
                            PrintWriter TEMP_OUT = new PrintWriter(TEMP_SOCK.getOutputStream(), true);
                            TEMP_OUT.println(inputLine);
                            TEMP_OUT.flush();                              
                            System.out.println("Sending to: " + TEMP_SOCK.getLocalAddress().getHostName());
                       }
                    }
                  if (inputLine.equals("Bye.")) 
                  break; 
             } 
             out.close(); 
             in.close(); 
             clientSocket.close(); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    { 
         System.err.println("Problem with Communication Server");
         System.exit(1); 
    } 
}
}
```

Client Class

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestClient  {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

    String serverHostname = new String ("127.0.0.1");

    if (args.length > 0)
       serverHostname = args[0];
    System.out.println ("Attemping to connect to host " +
            serverHostname);

    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, 22);
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                           + "the connection to: " + serverHostname);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    System.out.println ("Type Message (\"Bye.\" to quit)");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) 
    {           
        out.println(userInput);         

        if (userInput.equals("Bye."))
            break;

        System.out.println("Other user: " + in.readLine());
    }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        echoSocket.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate thread in the client for reading from the server without blocking on System.in;

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println("Other user: " + in.readLine());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
t.start();
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) 
{           
    out.println(userInput);         

    if (userInput.equals("Bye."))
        break;
}
t.interrupt();
```